# Starting Subroutine from Inside With Statement

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net to extract data from a software API into Excel. There are 5 different types of classes to extract data from but there are sections where the data to be extracted are the same. I have some examples below:

```
Dim builder1 as PocketBuilder = CreatePocketBuilder(op1)
With builder1
    Sheet1.Cells(1,1) = .Feeds.Value
    ...
    Something
End With

Dim builder2 as BossBuilder = CreateBossBuilder(op1)
With builder2
    Sheet1.Cells(1,1) = .Feeds.Value
    ...
    Something different
End With
```

As it can be seen above, some parts within the with statement are common, so I would like to find a method to put them in another subroutine to be called if possible. It was not possible to simply copy the common lines into another subroutine due to having no with statement wrapping them.

Comment: If you use succinct variable names then there's very little reason to use the `With... End With` statement at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do is have one method to act on several different class (`PocketBuilder`, `BossBuilder`, and three others), and use the same property names from each.

What you can do is have the items common to each in a class, and then [inherit](https://www.dotnetperls.com/class-vbnet) from that for `PocketBuilder`, `BossBuilder`, etc.

```
Module Module1

    Public Class ExcelSheetStandIn
        Public Property Cells As Object(,)
    End Class


    Public Class FeedData
        Public Property Items As List(Of String)

        Public ReadOnly Property Value() As String
            Get
                Return String.Join(", ", Items)
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class

    Public Class CommonItems
        Public Property Feeds As FeedData
        Public Property X As Double
        Public Property Y As Double

    End Class

    Public Class PocketBuilder
        Inherits CommonItems

        Public Property Depth As Decimal

    End Class

    Public Class BossBuilder
        Inherits CommonItems

        Public Property Diameter As Decimal

    End Class

    Public Sub SetValues(sheet As ExcelSheetStandIn, dataSource As CommonItems)
        sheet.Cells(1, 1) = dataSource.Feeds.Value
        sheet.Cells(2, 1) = dataSource.X
        sheet.Cells(3, 1) = dataSource.Y

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim xl As New ExcelSheetStandIn

        Dim builder1 As PocketBuilder = New PocketBuilder With {.Depth = 10D, .Feeds = New FeedData()}
        SetValues(xl, builder1)
        ' Something

        Dim builder2 As BossBuilder = New BossBuilder With {.Diameter = 5.2D, .Feeds = New FeedData()}
        SetValues(xl, builder2)
        ' Something different

    End Sub

End Module
```

So you can see that there is *one* `SetValues` method which can be used with any of the classes that inherit `CommonItems`.

Comment: This is too complicated (beyond my abilities) for me to make use of, but thank you.

Comment: @Cake You're welcome :) I'm sure you will be able to use if it you make a small program to practise with. I can't check properly at the moment, but the [Working with Classes and Inheritances in the .NET Framework Class Library](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Basic-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Working-with-Classes-and-Inheritances-in-the-NET-Framework-Class-Library-16) MSDN video is likely to explain it better than I can.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I can achieve what I require by declaring the "builder1" variable outside the module and changing the "builder2" variable to "builder1" as well. Doing so will allow my subroutine "SomeSub" to use the "builder1" variable.

Outside Module:
Dim builder1

Within Main:
builder1 = CreatePocketBuilder(op1)
Call SomeSub()
With builder1
    ...
    Something
End With

builder1 = CreateBossBuilder(op1)
Call SomeSub()
With builder1
    ...
    Something different
End With